# How to add user image details like date or time to file name while uploading photos to firebase storage?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, expo, firebase-storage

I am facing a problem related to uploading images in firebase storage. I am able to upload user images in firebase storage but it is only showing the newest image. it is not showing previous images. I think it is because of the path that I have created and the timestamp in this line of code:

```
 const path = 'photos/${Date.now()}.jpg';
```

I am using expo and React. Here is the code for uploading images:

```
uploadPhotoAsync = async uri => {
const path = 'photos/${Date.now()}.jpg';

return new Promise (async(res, rej) => {
    const response = await fetch(uri)
    const file = await response.blob()
    let upload = firebase.storage().ref(path).put(file)
    upload.on("state_changed", snapshot=>{

    }, err => {
        rej(err)
    }, async ()=>{
        const url = await upload.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL()
        res(url)
    })
})
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several errors in your code:

Template literals should be delimited with backticks (`), while you delimit yours with standard single quotes ('): `const path = 'photos/$(Date.now()}.jpg';`.

Result: The value of `path` is always the same.

In addition, after the `$` you use a parenthesis instead of a curly bracket.

Doing as follows shall do the trick:

```
const path = `photos/${Date.now()}.jpg`
```

Comment: Thank you so much! @Ranaud I had the correct parenthesis but the wrong template literals.